# DNN Module - Create Page for View.ascx

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have create a DNN Module using the Visual Studio DotNetNuke 7 C# Compiled Module template. When my module is installed, I would like to create a page for View.ascx. How can I do this? Can this be done when I upload the module in Host > Extensions?

Comment: Please look at the DotNetNuke Module development tutorials. This will answer all your questions. http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Training/Tutorials.aspx

Comment: Can you point me to a specific one? There are several tutorials there.

Answer (score 0):

From the Control Panel you should use the Add new page functionality, then place your Module on that newly created page.

Check out this video for how to Add a page in DNN7.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/549/View/Details/How-to-add-a-page-in-DotNetNuke-7.aspx

And this one for how to adda  module to a page

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library/Viewer/Video/537/View/Details/How-to-add-a-module-to-a-page-in-DotNetNuke-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question specifically about having this done automatically with the module, yes, you can, BUT you have to write code to do this and I only recommend it for special circumstances.

I've seen this done using an implementation of the IUpgradable interface in DNN to detect an initial installation and create the page using DNN API calls.

There is some detail in the [Wiki](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/IUpgradeable.aspx) about how IUpgradable works

Comment: I misread the original post, thanks for clarifying what he wants.